# Publish API REST in heroku

Tags: rest, heroku, swagger, slim

I need publish `API REST` in a hosting called [heroku](http://www.heroku.com). I have uploaded the project structure to the hosting through the necessary `git` commands. I have also created a database in `heroku` through `phpmyadmin` where in my `.env` file I specify the necessary data to access it:

```
DATABASE_HOST    = 'hostingmysql329.nominalia.com'
DATABASE_NAME    = 'comparador'
DATABASE_PORT    = 3306
DATABASE_USER    = 'user1'
DATABASE_PASSWD  = 'password'
DATABASE_DRIVER  = 'pdo_mysql'
DATABASE_CHARSET = 'UTF8'
```

The structure of the project is:

[image: STRUCTURE]

At the url: [app](http://pozascompare.herokuapp.com/public) I can see the `API` specification that I defined with `swagger` and `slim` but but when launching requests to the server I receive the following error:

[image: error]

When I make a request from the web page of my application I always get the error 404. I also think that the changes made in local are not being updated well when I upload them to the hosting. I use the commands:

- `git add .`
- `git commit -am "message"`
- `git push heroku master`

What can be wrong?
Any idea?

**swagger_error**

[image: swagger_error]

Comment: i try and look error when you call api. http://www.screencast.com/t/RHrTIK1ZZz9m

Comment: I can see the error: swagger_error that update in my questions @Hp Lam

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your swagger.json file contains an error here:

```
"host": "https://pozascompare.herokuapp.com",
             ^^
```

The `host` should not include the protocol. It should be:

```
"host": "pozascompare.herokuapp.com",
```

The supported protocols are specified by the `schemes` keyword.

Also, there are two operations with `operationId: deleteDestination`. Duplicate `operationId`s are not allowed. You can use https://editor.swagger.io to check for syntax errors in your spec.

Comment: I have modified what you say and now I get `404` error when making any request from swagger. Is there any way to know if the configuration with the database is correct? Should it be specified in the `.env` file or in another?

Comment: Is there a server-side for your API that would actually process the requests?

Comment: The server that process the requests is the hosting.
I had this `api rest` worked on my localhost but when uploading it to a hosting I found these errors @Helen